# Can the Front camera use autofocus?

Tags: android, camera, android-camera, autofocus

I am curious if the front camera of a Samsung galaxy s2 can use auto-focus with the front camera? There doesn't seem to be any documentation from Android to my knowledge.

Answer (score 2):

```
if (Camera.getNumberOfCameras() > 1) {
  final Camera camera = Camera.open(1);
  final String focusMode = camera.getParameters().getFocusMode();
  Log.v("FocusMode of front camera", focusMode);
}
```

=> "fixed"

> Focus is fixed. The camera is always in this mode if the focus is not adjustable.

Therefor, the answer is no.

Comment: It would be better to use `camera.getParameters().getSupportedFocusModes()` and check what modes does it contain.

Comment: But `camera.getParameters().getSupportedFocusModes()` returns for back camera. not sure for front camera.